# Can cuda atomic operations use L1 cache?

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu, atomic, gpgpu

cc: 7.5 Windows: 10.0 cuda: 11.7

I'm performing a bunch of atomic operations on device memory.  Every thread in a warp is operating on a consecutive uint32_t.  And every warp in the block updates those same values, before they all move on to the next line.

Since I'm not using any shared memory, I was hoping that it would be used to cache the device memory, effectively doing an atomicAnd against shared memory without all the overhead and headaches of syncthreads and copying the data around.

But the performance suggests that's not what's happening.

Indeed, looking at NSight, it's saying there's a 0% hit rate in L1 cache.  Ouch.  The memory workload analysis also shows 0% Hit under Global Atomic ALU.

Google turned up [one hit](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/atomic-operation-unit/17392) (somewhat dated) suggesting that atomic is always done via L2 for device memory.  Not exactly an authoritative source, but it matches what I'm seeing.  On the other hand, there's [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/memorystatisticsatomics.htm) which seems to suggest it does (did?) go thru L1.  A more authoritative source, but not exactly on point.

Could I have something misconfigured?  Maybe my code isn't doing what I think it is?  Or do atomic operations against device memory always go thru L2?

- I tried using [RED](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-red) instead of atomics, but that didn't make any difference.
- I also tried using atomicAnd_block instead of just atomicAnd, and somehow that made things even slower?  Not what I expected.
- I'd like to experiment with [redux](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-redux-sync), but cc 8.0 isn't an option for me yet.  __shfl_sync turned out to be disappointing (performance-wise).

At this point I'm inclined to believe that in 7.5, atomics on device memory always go thru L2.  But if someone has evidence to the contrary, I can keep digging.

Comment: If L1 caches aren't coherent in a GPU the way they are in a CPU, that would prevent the CPU "cache lock" mechanism from working, where a core holds on to MESI ownership of a line for the duration of its atomic RMW.  So it's plausible that it has to be this way, but upvoted in hopes of getting a real answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have no idea how cache line ownership is handled on cuda devices.  But I would have expected that atomicAnd_block (which by definition all run on the same processor) would have allowed for sharing L1 data.  At this point it's about 50-50 whether I'm doing something wrong, or whether this just isn't going to work the way I want.

Comment: Memory writes to L1 for anything that isn't local memory is madness. For starters, what if a later GPU generation has a larger cache size and your thread-blocks are no longer cache-aligned? When and how do you evict the updates from L1? Plus latency in L1 is higher than in shared memory. So you shoot yourself in the foot anyway.

Comment: @Homer512 Writes to device memory pass through L1 all the time.  Seems like there'd already have to be some way to keep things in sync.  Although it's possible that the *way* they keep things in sync is to always immediately write L1 changes to L2.  But in that case, I'd kind of expect that the atomicAnd from the next thread in the same block would get the benefit of a cache hit.  And I'm not seeing that in NSight.  Could be just a reporting thing, but I just don't know.

Answer (score 3):

As usual with Nvidia, concrete information is hard to come by. But we can have a look at the [PTX documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) and infer a few things.

### Atomic load and store

Atomic loads and stores use variations of their regular `ld` and `st` instructions which have the following pattern:

```
ld{.weak}{.ss}{.cop}{.level::cache_hint}{.level::prefetch_size}{.vec}.type  d, [a]{, cache-policy};
ld.sem.scope{.ss}{.level::eviction_priority}{.level::cache_hint}{.level::prefetch_size}{.vec}.type;

st{.weak}{.ss}{.cop}{.level::cache_hint}{.vec}.type   [a], b{, cache-policy};
st.sem.scope{.ss}{.level::eviction_priority}{.level::cache_hint}{.vec}.type [a], b{, cache-policy};
```

`weak` loads and stores are regular memory operations. The `cop` part specifies the cache behavior. For our purposes, there is `ld.cg` (cache-global) that only uses the L2 cache and `ld.ca` (cache-all), which uses L1 and L2 cache. As the documentation notes:

> Global data is coherent at the L2 level, but multiple L1 caches are not coherent for global data. If one thread stores to global memory via one L1 cache, and a second thread loads that address via a second L1 cache with `ld.ca`, the second thread may get stale L1 cache data, rather than the data stored by the first thread. The driver must invalidate global L1 cache lines between dependent grids of parallel threads. Stores by the first grid program are then correctly fetched by the second grid program issuing default `ld.ca` loads cached in L1.

Similarly, there is `st.cg` which caches only in L2. It "bypasses the L1 cache." The wording isn't precise but it sounds as if this should invalidate the L1 cache. Otherwise even within a single thread, a sequence of `ld.ca; st.cg; ld.ca` would read stale data and that sounds like an insane idea.

The second relevant `cog` for write is `st.wb` (write-back). The wording in the documentation is very weird. I guess this writes back to L1 cache and may later evict to L2 and up.

The `ld.sem` and `st.sem` (where sem is one of relaxed, acquire, or release) are the true atomic loads and stores. Scope gives the, well, scope of the synchronization, meaning for example whether an acquire is synchronized within a thread block or on the whole GPU.

Notice how these operations have no `cop` element. So you cannot even specify a cache layer. You can give cache hints but I don't see how those are sufficient to specify the desired semantics. `cache_hint` and `cache-policy` only work on L2.

Only the `eviction_priority` mentions L1. But just because that performance hint is accepted does not mean it has any effect. I assume it works for weak memory operations but for atomics, only the L2 policies have any effect. But this is just conjecture.

### Atomic Read-modify-write

The `atom` instruction is used for atomic exchange, compare-and-swap, addition, etc. `red` is used for reductions. They have the following structure:

```
atom{.sem}{.scope}{.space}.op{.level::cache_hint}.type d, [a], b{, cache-policy};
red{.sem}{.scope}{.space}.op{.level::cache_hint}.type     [a], b{, cache-policy};
```

With these elements:

- sem: memory synchronization behavior, such as as acquire, release, or relaxed
- scope: memory synchronization scope, e.g. acquire-release within a CTA (thread block) or GPU
- space: global or shared memory
- cache policy, level and hint: cache eviction policy. But there are no options for L1, only L2

**Given that there is no way to specify L1 caching or write-back behavior, there is no way of using atomic RMW operations on L1 cache.** This makes a lot of sense to me. Why should the GPU waste transistors on implementing this? Shared memory exists for the exact purpose of allowing fast memory operations within a thread block.

Comment: "not coherent for global data" - So there's already the idea of global data being cached (and written) in L1, then flushed at a future time? Seems like that's exactly what atomicAnd_block would be intended to do.  What does `atom.cta` mean otherwise? "no way of using atomic RMW operations on L1 cache" - Except you can if you call that same memory "shared." What changed besides the name and the need to flush (which it apparently already supports)? I'm not saying you're wrong (you're probably right). But we're both kinda guessing. Still, upvoted for being a well thought out and supported answer.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I don't think there is a cache flush instruction. Only a cache discard instruction. So the only way to flush changes from L1 cache is to finish the entire grid (according to the quote above). Regarding ```atom.cta```, I interpret that more as a weaker memory barrier, e.g. if the SM supports load-store forwarding across threads, we wouldn't need to flush the store buffer. But I actually don't know. Regarding shared memory, it's got lower latency, no aliasing, is simpler, etc. I don't know what to tell you, it's just a different piece of hardware.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd one more note re. ```atom.cta```: It's a pretty common pattern to have multiple atomic operations with weak or no synchronization, followed by a memory fence. But if ```atom.cta``` does a write-back to L1, this cannot work unless mfence flushes that cache (which it doesn't). Because there is no flush instruction, any write to L1 cache effectively "curses" the memory location to only ever be safe to access through that L1 cache. The only way around this would be to reload with ```ld.ca``` and store again with ```st.cg```. That can't be an intended use.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I'd also like to emphasize just how bad of an idea I think it is to use a non-coherent cache for any kind of multithreaded operation. The moment you mess up your cache alignment (or a future GPU comes with a larger than anticipated cache line size), you end up with a hard-to-debug issue. That's why it's so hard to find any information on this. It feels like looking for buoyancy information in a car's manual. The moment you need that info, you've already made a wrong turn.